# Ruby - Why does sort reorder equal elements

Tags: ruby, sorting

I'm trying to reverse sort an array of hashes without changing the order of hashes that are equal. However I am not seeing this functionality with `sort`.

For example,

```
[{a:1, b:2}, {a:0, b:5}, {a:1,b:4}, {a:1,b:3}].sort { |a,b| b[:a] <=> a[:a] }
# actual:   [{:a=>1, :b=>2}, {:a=>1, :b=>3}, {:a=>1, :b=>4}, {:a=>0, :b=>5}]
# expected: [{:a=>1, :b=>2}, {:a=>1, :b=>4}, {:a=>1, :b=>3}, {:a=>0, :b=>5}]
```

The hashes with `:b=>4` and `:b=>3` are incorrectly re-ordered.  Am I  misinterpreting how sort works?

Comment: Isn't your expected and first line's output same? What are you exactly doing/asking?

Comment: Yes, the first command and output is what I expect to happen.  The second set is where it's not what I expect.

Comment: So, you're saying that one of the most used methods in a language isn't returning the results you expect so it has a defect?

Comment: @theTinMan Asking, not saying.

Comment: OK, so, you're *asking* if sort, one of the most used methods in the language, has a defect because it isn't returning the results you expect?

Comment: Sorry for the big edit/rollback. I think your question was actually unclear because it was _too long_.

Comment: So I was looking for behavior like Bubblesort instead of Quicksort.  That's where my confusion was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array#sort` uses a quicksort algorithm under the hood. This algorithm is not *stable*: there is no guarantee that equal elements will not be reordered in the output. Basically when you sort in Ruby, you should specify *exactly* how things should be sorted rather than leave it up to chance. You can handle your case by using `sort_by` and adding the element's index to the sorting criteria:

```
ary.sort_by.with_index { |h, i| [-h[:a], i] }
```

Comment: `sort_by` can also make it a heck of a lot faster.

Comment: @TIMBERings Ah, you expect `Array#sort` to be *stable*, that is to not rearrange equal elements in the array. I shall edit.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with @theTinMan. I wouldn't even bother with `sort` unless it was strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2):

It looks you have issue with the fact that it reordered some of the entries in the array that had a matching value. This is because of the quicksort algorithm used by the native ruby sort.

You read about quicksort here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort and an article about ruby implentation here https://www.igvita.com/2009/03/26/ruby-algorithms-sorting-trie-heaps.

The result you get is sorted properly based on the sort criteria, but it may reorder some of the similar entries in the process.